# How to open context menu without keyboard onLongPress on TextInput (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

In the chat (React Native) application I need to be able `onLongPress` to open context menu without the keyboard, but on normal tap/shortPress open up a keyboard. Like in most of the messengers out there.

The current behavior of `TextInput` on blur(not focused), `onLongPress` it brings up both the context menu and the keyboard.

Comment: Share your code snippet. what you did.

Comment: This is default behavior of `<TextInput>. I have empty textInput and its doing that

Comment: Check out @Mehul answer that may help you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way, that may solve your problem,

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.isClickable();

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

inside `OnLongClickLitener` return `true` that indicate you don't want further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways

1. Disable it from the AndroidManifest file as follows
   inside the activity which you need to disable the keyboard apply the 
   **windowSoftInputMode** as **"stateHidden"**

   **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"**
2. Change From the XML file
   You can put focusable= false on EditText

   **android:focusable="false"**